# Changing the name of a test class at runtime

Tags: java, junit4

Is there anyway that I can rename a test class at runtime?

[Backstory: I have a bunch of files that are transformed into tests, and will probably be parameterized, however all of the files use the same test logic, and I will not create new classes for every file just to get that name]

I am using the latest Junit 4.11.

Comment: Maybe you should rethink how your tests are organized in the first place.

Comment: I think there is some problem with design. Write your tests first!

Comment: I can't do that. The tests are generated by external files. Each file represents a distinctly unique test set. I can just put all of this within a parameterized test, but that would end up causing 200+ test methods to be grouped under a single test file.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit has introduced naming of parameterized tests. The original bug request for this feature is here: https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/issues/44. From some Googling, I believe this is present in JUnit 4.11 (but I'm not 100% sure).

If your files are just test data being fed into a number of parameterized tests, I can see it would be easy to add a name attribute into the mix to give you the functionality you desire.